# ng-repeat with groupBy issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Supposed I have the below array of `users`:

```
$scope.users = [
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "status": "pending"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "status": "pending"
    },
    {
        "name": "baz",
        "status": "active"
    },
    {
        "name": "qux",
        "status": "confirmed"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to generate a grouped list based on two `status` properties.
The output should be two lists as such

### List 1

```
pending, confirmed
-> foo, bar, qux
```

### List 2

```
active
-> baz
```

What i'm currently doing is

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in users | groupBy: 'status'"
```

But this of course fails because the output would be three groups (confirmed, active and pending) instead of two as needed above.

Is it possible to merge the two statuses using this `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Have you tried groupBy: ['pending','success']

Comment: @user  if u can add the full code it will be easy to help you. just a line of ng-repeat is not enough

Answer (score 0):

You could do this separation in your controller and your view consume the result. So you would have two `ng-repeat`, one for the users with status pending or confirmed and the other for the users with active status.

```js
// I don't have the full code. So I defined a scope object here
// You don't have to define a scope like this, since you inject it
// in you controller.
var $scope = {};

$scope.pendingConfirmed = [];
$scope.active = [];
var users = [
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "status": "pending"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "status": "pending"
    },
    {
        "name": "baz",
        "status": "active"
    },
    {
        "name": "qux",
        "status": "confirmed"
    }
];

for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
    var user = users[i];
    if( user.status === "pending" 
     || user.status === "confirmed" ){
        $scope.pendingConfirmed.push(user);
    } else {
        if( user.status === "active" ){
            $scope.active.push(user);
        }
    }
}


console.log('-- Pending or Confirmed --');
console.log($scope.pendingConfirmed);
console.log('-- Active --');
console.log($scope.active);
```

Comment: strange use of filter() just to loop the array and not return anything

Comment: @charlietfl you have a strong point. I will change it to a `for`. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you can fix like this

```html
ng-repeat="(key, value) in users | groupBy: 'status'" | toArray:true
```

Comment: What's the output of this? I don't think it helps.